# How can I get the channel ID of the channel that a Discord bot's command was run in?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Whenever someone runs a command, how do I store the ID of the channel he ran the command in?
~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    console.log(`A message from ${message.author.tag} was sent in the channel with the ID: ${message.channel.id}.`);
});
```